# ERROR : Duplicate Subscription has been detected while using Reactive webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, completable-future

I am using spring webflux client to call reactive apis.
It is resulting into this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spec. Rule 2.12 - Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once (based on object equality)
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.duplicateOnSubscribeException(Exceptions.java:181)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.reportSubscriptionSet(Operators.java:1083)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.setOnce(Operators.java:1188)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:102)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.reportThrowInSubscribe(Operators.java:225)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4255)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4363)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.toFuture(Mono.java:4697)
    at abc.bcd.cde.fgh.SettingsRepositoryImplP2.getApplicationSettings(SettingsRepositoryImplP2.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
    at abc.bcd.cde.fgh.ApplicationSettingsCache.hasMaxCapture(ApplicationSettingsCache.java:38)
    at abc.bcd.cde.fgh.ApplicationDebugService.shouldBeCaptured(ApplicationDebugService.java:20)
    at abc.bcd.cde.fgh.ApplicationDebugService.lambdaf865c(ApplicationDebugService.java:26)
    at akka.stream.javadsl.Flow.(Flow.scala:739)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync96775anon.onPush(Ops.scala:1307)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:542)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:423)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:521)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka96775processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:800)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka96775shortCircuitBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:787)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter96775anonfun.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:819)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:716)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage96775(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec96775(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

My Call looks like this

```
public Mono<TestSettings> retrieveApplicationConfiguration(String applicationId) {

        var url = applicationConfigurationServiceUrl.concat("/conf").concat("/{id}");

        return webClient.get()
                .uri(url, applicationId)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                        (clientResponse -> {
                            log.info("Status code : {}", clientResponse.statusCode().value());
                            if (clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) {
                                //return TestSettings.captureABC();
                                return Mono.error(new ApplicationConfigServiceException("Error fetching Applications for application " + applicationId, clientResponse.statusCode().value()));
                            }
                            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                    .flatMap(response -> Mono.error(new ApplicationConfigServiceException(" Error fetching Applications for " + applicationId + response, clientResponse.statusCode().value())));
                        }))
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        (clientResponse -> {
                        log.info("Status code : {}", clientResponse.statusCode().value());
                        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                            .flatMap(response -> Mono.error(new ApplicationConfigServiceException(response, clientResponse.statusCode().value())));
                }))
                .bodyToMono(ApplicationConfigurationResponse.class)
                .map(a -> {
                    log.info("LOG : {}", a);
                    return TestSettings.create(a);
                })
                //.retryWhen(WebClientRetryUtil.retrySpec())
                .log();
    }
```

and webclient call is then used as below. here i am converting `Mono` to `CompletableFuture`.

```
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<TestSettings> getApplicationSettings(String application) {
        return webClient.retrieveApplicationConfiguration(application)
                .toFuture();
    }
```

### EDIT 1

There is one method upstream which is calling `getApplicationSettings()` and from where error is originating.
`fetchSettings::fetch` is a function passed as an argument.

```
return testSettingsMap
    .computeIfAbsent(app, testSettings::fetch)
    .thenApply(TestSettings::debugSettings)
    .thenApply(s -> s.equals(MAXIMUM));
```

Note :testSettingsMap is a ConcurrentHashMap `private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture<TestSettings>> testSettingsMap;`

How can I debug or fix this problem ?

Comment: could you show the code that calls getApplicationSettings() method?

Comment: Added details in EDIT